# [Question not accurate]Handle json string with quote in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string

I have an issue to deal with a configuration file in json with python.
My configuration file is 'config.json':
`{"Pressure": ["", "mbar", "\"H2O", "\"Hg", "PSI"]}`

In python, I want to compare a string "H2O obtain from a PyQt Combobox (.currentText())  to \"H2O of the json file but I am never able to have a correct match.

How can I correctly handle the \"H2O for the string comparison with "H2O?

**Old example program for history:**

```py
with open("config.json", "rt") as json_lfile:
    cfg = json.load(json_lfile)
pressure = cfg["Pressure"]
for i in range(len(pressure)):
    print(pressure[i])
    if "H2O" == pressure[i]:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("NOK")
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Use `'"H2O'` instead?

Comment: While making a [example] it's recommended to hard code values that is obtained by more complex functions -- for example you can replace the file read with the object itself.

Comment: I made some precisions to my questions because there was an obvious error in the code.  
My issue is with a string from a PyQt5 Combobox that gives me "H2O but is not equivalent to the json \"H2O.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `"HSO` with single-quotes

```
if '"H2O' == pressure[i]:
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `'"H2O'` instead as `O O` says. Plus you can simplify things a bit:

```py
with open("config.json", "rt") as json_lfile:
    cfg = json.load(json_lfile)
for value in cfg["Pressure"]:
    print(value)
    if '"H2O' == value:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("NOK")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for item in pressure:
    print(item)
    if 'H2O' in item:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("NOK")
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON parser will look at the quote within the ""H2O" string and parse it as an actual quote, effectively ending the string before it reads H in H2O. You want to escape the quote within the string so the parser doesn't treat it as a string delimiter.

Just replace `""H2O"` with `"\\"H2O"` or `'"H2O'` in your JSON file and the error should go away.

To compare it just do the same to the string in your code: escape the inner quote.